# Computing the Radius of Curvature of a Bezier Curve Given Control Points

Tags: bezier

I'm trying to write a genetic algorithm with curvature as one of the optimization parameters. I want to calculate curvature based on the control points of a bezier curve. I have a minimum radius of curvature that I want to be optimized for. I've been referencing this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01524.pdf

In the paper there is a function that takes the side lengths of a triangle to get the implied radius of curvature, which I have implemented. Here is my current code:

```
// Computes the curvature implied by 3 control points of a bezier curve
float curvature(float4 p0, float4 p1, float4 p2) {

    // Get the triangle side lengths
    float a = distance(p0, p1);
    float b = distance(p1, p2);
    float c = distance(p2, p0);

    // Do the curvature calculation
    float num = a * b * c;
    float denom = (a + b + c) * (b + c - a) * (a - b + c) * (a + b - c);

    return num / sqrt(denom);

}
```

The results of this function seem to be incorrect. I run this function for every point in the path, save the last two and then get the minimum radius out of all of them. When I graph the path, there seems to be a major discrepancy between this function's calculation and what I can see visually. Whats the right method to do this?

EDIT: 
I was looking to calculate the radius of curvature between three control points, not at a given point in the curve, apologies if this was unclear.

Comment: The function that you've implemented does not seem to match the actual function for radius of curvature for parametric planar curves.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah this is what I was thinking, the paper I was working from used this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The radius of curvature R(t) is equal to 1/κ(t), where κ(t) is the curvature of the curve at point t, which for [a parametric planar curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions) is:

```
            x'y" - y'x"
κ(t)  = --------------------
         (x'² + y'²)^(3/2)
```

(Where the `^(3/2)` is really <sup>3/2</sup>, but you can't use html for superscript formatting in code blocks, and where the (t) part has been left off the functions for x and y because that makes things unnecessarily hard to read)

As such, for a Quadratic Bezier curve with controls P₁, P₂, and P₃, [the first and second derivatives use the following control points](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives):

```
B(t)': P₁' = 2(P₂ - P₁), and P₂' = 2(P₃ - P₂)
B(t)": P₁" = (P'₂ - P'₁)
```

Evaluating these for x and y are literally just "using the x or y coordinates", so:

```
x' = Px₁'(t-1) + Px₂'(t)
y' = Py₁'(t-1) + Py₂'(t)
x" = Px₁"
y" = Py₁"
```

Noting that x" and y" are just constants. We plug these values into the function for κ(t), provided that the denominator isn't zero, of course (which indicates a line segment, which has no radius of curvature) and then we know what R(t) is because that's just the inverse value.

But we don't actually need to do any of that, because we can make a simple observation: treating the circle as a parametric curve as well, we can find its radius pretty much immediately based on the fact that the vector length of the derivative of the curve, and the derivative of the circle at the same point, are equal. Additionally, we know that the length of the derivative is the same anywhere on a circle (because it's a circle, which by definition is radially symmetric about the origin). As such, we can solve the following:

```
B(t)  = P1(1-t)^2 + 2*P2(1-t)t + P3t^2
B(t)' = 2*(P2-P1)(1-t) + 2*(P3-P2)t

C(s)  = { r*sin(s), r*cos(s) }independent of 't')
C(s)' = { r*cos(s), -r*sin(s) }

d = |B(t)'| = |C(s = any value, so let's pick 0)'|
d = C(0)' = | (r,0) | = r
```

And we're done. The radius of curvature at point B(t) is equal to the vector length of B(t)', which is much easier to implement, and much faster to run.

Finally, if what you actually want is to just approximate sections of curve with circular arcs, then https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arcapproximation  should cover the "how to" for that particular use-case.

Comment: I was a bit unclear what I was looking for in the question, and I apologize. I was looking more for a way to get the radius of curvature given 3 points in the curve, rather than evaluate curvature at a given point on the curve.

Comment: You can't, you can only compute radius of arc for Bezier curves "at a point", not "over an interval", so it sounds like what you *actually* want is a way to approximate sections of a curve to circular arcs. In which case https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arcapproximation covers that.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by 'Evaluating these for x and y are literally just "using the x or y coordinates"' and the relation between this and the fact that e.g. `x' = Px₁'(t-1) + Px₂'(t)`. Where does this definition of `x'` come from (with respect to the definition of `B(t)'`, which is defined in terms of the derivative of two points, which is not clear what that even means)?

Comment: See https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives (explicitly linked in the post right before the second code block) which explains in detail why the derivatives are what I claim they are. Bezier derivatives are incredibly easy to write out, because each derivative is one fewer coordinate, and the derivative coordinates are very easy and clean interpolations of the original set. In order to form the x', y', x'', and y'' terms we start with the quadratic x and y formulae, and just reduce them as per the rules of Bezier derivation. Since we know `t`, all of them evaluate to constants.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans _In order to form the x', y', x'', and y'' terms we start with the quadratic x and y formulae, and just reduce them as per the rules of Bezier derivation_, what do you mean by "rules of Bezier derivation"? By the way, I am not familiar with Bezier. I was trying to understand your derivation so that to apply it to the case of Catmull-Rom splines.

Comment: Then this is not the place to ask me to help you learn Bezier curves. Start reading https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/, and you might even want to start with section 33, which shows how CR and Bezier curves are two different ways to write out the _exact same curve_, with almost trivial conversion between the two notations.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Now, I just want to understand what you mean by "rules of Bezier derivation". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Literally that: the rules for computing the derivative of any Bezier function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ok. The word "derivation" has different meanings, so that's why I wanted you to clarify this point.

Comment: ... did you maybe miss the mathematical notation that made it perfectly clear which derivation we were talking about? The prime (and double prime, etc) denote derivative. That's how English maths notation works, and this is a [primarily English website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/395686)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What confused me is that I didn't think there was a specific way of deriving the Bezier curve. I thought we just applied the rules of calculus.

Comment: There is no "just" there: we _are_ applying the rules of calculus, and because the Bezier function is a very special kind of function, we can either take the long way round to find the derivative (see book), or we can observe what that long way round _ends up giving us_ and then using that as a stupidly easy shortcut because there is no reason to go through the entire step-wise derivation every single time when we can also just run a single step derivation that we know (because we proved it somewhere else) is correct.

Comment: « The radius of curvature at point B(t) is equal to the vector length of B(t)' » There are infinitly many nth-order Bézier curves that are segments *and have non-zero derivative*. They are not hard to find (just align the control points between the start and end points) yet they all have κ(t) = 0 for all t...

Comment: I'm afraid your "proof" based on an analogy with circles only holds for circles.

Comment: You have 132 rep: you [know how this site works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you have a better answer, post a better answer, if you have improvements to contribute to an existing answer, [leave constructive comments](/conduct). If you just want to say "this is wrong", then you're not helping anyone, so: please either post an answer of your own, or say what you'd like to see updated on this one.

Comment: I've already said what I'd like to be improved in answer. More clarity around « The radius of curvature at point B(t) is equal to the vector length of B(t)' » which is a misleading statement.

Comment: works for me, I'll go and delete all my comments relating to this.

Comment: I like the answer very much - it was quite helpful to me. I want to add two statements: 
* The minimal radius for a uniform quadratic Bezier curve (|P1->P2| == |P2->Pr|) is B'(.5)
* To find the minimal radius for a general quadratic Bezier curve, one needs to find min_t B'(t) for t in (0,1).
If the latter is better tested (e.g. via bisection) or by minimizing the polynom, I did not try.